# How can I Like Facebook Video using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, video

I am a newbie at facebook integration. I want to retrieve only videos from facebook page into my website and a user can like that video from my website.

I am getting video from facebook using [https://graph.facebook.com/{page_name}/videos](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage_name%7D/videos)

Somehow, I can retrieve the video into my website but I don't know how to implement like button using CodeIgniter.

Can anyone guide me how can achieve this?

Comment: This may help - not sure how up to date it is: http://thephpx.com/2010/06/codeigniter-facebook-social-plugin-like-button-helper/

Comment: thanks @Mick but what i need to pass in $url